# Free form input in terminal?

Tags: free-form-input

I am using Mathematica 8. Is there a way to use free form input through the terminal? Using the notebook is not an option for me.

I want to do things like "optimize x^2 on [1, 4]" without having to type excessive notation. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the answer is "no". AFAIK support for free form input is implemented in the front-end and requires an internet connection because a Wolfram server does the actual processing of the free form input

Comment: Using Mathematica without the front end is not a very good idea.  Only do it if you absolutely do not have any other choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) like this:

```
WolframAlpha["optimize x^2 on [1, 4]", "Result"]

(* {{1, {x -> 1}}, {16, {x -> 4}}} *)
```

This *requires* the front end.  It does not require an actual screen, and will work in terminal mode, but the front end must be able to run somehow.  If you are accessing a headless Linux machine through SSH, there must still be a running X server.  The typical way is to use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), but ssh X forwarding (`-X` option) may work too.